# react + vite + capacitor retorna pantalla negra en android

Tags: android, reactjs, vite, capacitor

Al generar una aplicación desde cero de react con vite, funciona correctamente.

**creo aplicación**

```
npm init vite@latest dummy -- --template react

cd dummy

npm install

npm run dev
```

**instalo capacitor**

```
npm i @capacitor/cli @capacitor/core

npx cap init

npm i @capacitor/android

npx cap add android
```

**compilo aplicación**

```
npm run build

npx cap sync

npx cap open android
```

La compilación es exitosa, pero al intentar ejecutarlo en el emulador, retorna pantalla negra.

ejecutando `brave://inspect/#devices` veo que devuelve el siguiente error

```
VM22:635 SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
cap.handleError.err @ VM22:635
index-e92ae01e.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

gracias de antemano a todos

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso el error que se muestra es el siguiente:

JavaScript Error: {"type":"js.error","error":{"message":"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?","url":"https://localhost/assets/index-1c4f73be.js","line":37,"col":3286,"errorObject":"{}"}}

La misma versión de la app funciona sin errores en Chrome o en Firefox, por lo que es un error del webview del emulador de Android. Cuando voy a la línea donde se encuentra el error tiene un operador "??" (Nullish coalescing), por lo que estimo que la versión del webview no está actualizada y no es compatible con la que usa Vite para generar la versión build (https://caniuse.com/?search=nullish%20coalescing)..

Aún no he logrado solucionarlo, pero si no me equivoco lo único que resta hacer es bajar la versión de build que usa Vite para que la app resultante sea compatible con webview más viejos.

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/390994)